# "could not locate gemfile" when doing bundle install on existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundle, locate, gemfile

I've been given an existing rails project that I am trying to play around with. however, when I try to run bundle install or rake db:migrate, I run into problems so essentially, i can't really do anything with the code I've been given.

The biggest problem as I see it right now is the fact that it can't locate my gemfile when I bundle install?

How can I find my gemfile.. is there supposed to be one in the root folder of the application?

Is there another step I need to take to initialize an existing project that someone has just copied and pasted to me? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Is the app definitely using bundler? There's no guarantee - worth checking in config/environment.rb for `config.gem` calls in which case it might not be.

Comment: you are correct there is no config.gem call.

Comment: the gem version is the following: RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.0.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

i'm just getting "could not locate gemfile" when I call bundle install. If that is not a valid command for this app, what should I be doing instead to install gems the app is dependent on? Thanks

Comment: What is the rails application version?  Gemfiles were introduced in 3+ so it's quite possible you have a 2+ version, especially since you 'inherited' it.

Comment: n.b. 2.x versions can also have gemfiles added to them (which I have done) and switched to bundler, just not the standard.

Comment: without s agem file the procedure is to (first) do gem install the_gem_name at the command line.  They add the reference to the gem in your config/environment.rb file.

Comment: i tried running this to get the rails version, Rails::VERSION::STRING, but it gives me "sh.exe: Rails::VERSION::STRING command not found". problem with the installing gems separating procedure is that I don't know what gems are required by the app. how wud i go about doing that?

Comment: does anyone know how to get this application runningg?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should have a `Gemfile` in the root directory of your app.

If you are developing in a Rails 2 app, you might want to check out the Bundler.io page about Rails 2.3:

http://bundler.io/v1.7/rails23.html

If you are using Rails 3+ you can take a learn from Bundler's page on Rails 3 use:

http://bundler.io/v1.7/rails3.html

If you just need to get started with a `Gemfile`, go to a different directory and generate a dummy app:

```
$ rails new temporary-app
```

Copy over the `Gemfile` to your directory. It will only have the default gems listed, but you may be able to "discover" your needed gems as you go.  If you happen to have a `Gemfile.lock` file then you can see the gems that you need at the top of the dependency tree.